# Proof that every point of every open set $E⊂ℝ^2$ is a limit point of $E$?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

NOTE: There are some other similar questions, but I wanted to know if my proof is valid. Also note this is a graded assignment.

> 8. Is every point of every open set $E⊂{ℝ}^2$ a limit point of E? Answer the same question for closed sets in $E⊂{ℝ}^2$

*From Principles of Mathematical Analysis*

---

**Proof:** By definition, as E is an open set, all points that belong to $E$ are interior points. Therefore there exists a neighborhood for all points of $E$ such that neighborhood $N ⊂ E$. A neighborhood on a plane (in ${ℝ}^2$) is a disk with a radius $r > 0$.

We now have:
For $∀p$, such that $p∈E$, there there exists a neighborhood ${N_p} ⊂ E$ with a radius $r > 0$.

Then there exists a $q$, such that $q∈N_p$ and $q ≠ p$. Let $p$ (an ordered pair) = $(x_1, y_1)$ and $q$ (also an ordered pair) = $(x_2, y_2)$. Therefore, there exists another point, $m$, between $p$ and $q$. $ m = (\frac{x_1+x_2}{2} , \frac{y_1+y_2}{2})$. Therefore p is a limit point. [QED]

Part 2: Counterexample. The set {(0,0)} is closed and (0,0) is not a limit point of $E$.

---

I am new to this area of mathematics, so I hope my proof isn't a total mess. I don't think it is very good and I would like advice on this proof and whether or not it is valid. I worry it has the correct idea but perhaps it is incomplete (do I need to use induction to show that for all points m, there is another m between it and p?).

Comment: If I were grading, I would say that your proof is correct, albeit a bit of a mess.  You definitely have the right ideas here, but you supply a lot of superfluous explanation that ultimately makes things harder to read, and you go through some "extra steps". If I find the time, I'll post what I think is a "cleaner" version.

Comment: Also, I'm used to a different notation for neighborhoods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, I don't think you ever arrive at the definition of a limit point, so your proof is not complete. In particular, you haven't shown that *every* neighborhood of $p$ contains an element of $E$.

---

Here's what I think of as a "cleaner" and completed version of your proof:

> **Claim:** Every point of an open set $E \subset \Bbb R^2$ is a limit point.

**Proof:**
Consider a point $p = (x_1,y_1) \in E$. By the definition of an open set, there exists an $r>0$ such that $N_r(p) \subset E$. We note that for any $s$ such that $0 < s < r$, the point $q_s = (x_1 + s,y_1)$ satisfies $d(p,q) = s$. So, $q_s \in N_{r}(p) \subset E$.

Thus, for every $\epsilon > 0$, if we select $s$ with $0<s < \min\{\epsilon,r\}$, then we find $q_s \in E$, $d(p,q_s) < \epsilon$, and $q_s \neq p$.  It follows that $p$ is a *limit point* of $E$.

Comment: I am always very confused by the ϵ. I don't see where that comes in at and it just seems to get mentioned… I think this is one of the hardest things for me to get out of analysis.

Comment: Usually there's an $\epsilon$ in the definition of a limit point.  If you have a definition that *doesn't* use an epsilon, we could use that instead and avoid $\epsilon$s all together.

Comment: I don't really get what r is if not ϵ.

Comment: What is the textbook's definition of a limit point?

Comment: It uses r instead. I think I figured it out. I made a MUCH shorter proof basically using definitions. It is like a neighborhood except that one only must find one other point within r rather than all points, correct? Is that the idea of ϵ? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think you have the right idea

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: every point of open set E in $R^2$ is limit point of E then can we say that E is closed? As all it's points are limit point?

Comment: @ASHWINI every point of $E$ is a limit point of $E$, but it doesn’t necessarily hold that every limit point of $E$ is a point of $E$. So no: $E$ will not necessarily be closed

Comment: Sir, sorry for doing comment on such a old post. But I think same is ture for $E\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is am I correct?

Comment: @Akash yes, you are correct.

Comment: @BenGrossmann i think u have done some typo mistake that $p=(x_1,y_1) $  i guess it should be $p=(x_1,x_2)$

Comment: @jasmine I've fixed it now