# Is every point of every open set $E \subset R^2 $ a limit point of E?(Proof-verification)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

NOTE: There are some other similar questions, but I got a negative answer to this question from my proof. Please find out the errors in my reasoning.

$\mathbf {Claim:}$ Is every point of every open set $E \subset R^2$ a limit point of E? Answer the same question for closed sets in $E \subset R^2$

From "Baby Rudin"

$\mathbf {Proof:}$ $\emptyset$ is both open and closed in every topological space. $R^2$ is a metric space, which is a kind of topological space, so $\emptyset$ is both open and closed in it. $\emptyset$ has no limit point because its neighborhood has no other point to include, so we can get a negative answer to both questions.

If possible, please have a look at the two questions that I got while reading the answer to this similiar question:
[Proof that every point of every open set E⊂ℝ^2 is a limit point of E?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446589/proof-that-every-point-of-every-open-set-e)⊂ℝ2-is-a-limit-point-of-e

1. "$q_s=(x_1+s,x_2)$" should be $q_s=(x_1+s,y_1)$, right?
2. I still don't understand why there should be $\epsilon$. Why can't r complete the proof?

I don't have the right to comment on the original post led by the above link, so I ask the two questions here.
Finally, I find this forum very active, responsive and helpful, but not quite friendly to newcomers.

Comment: Yes for open sets, no for closed sets. For instance a singleton is closed, but has no limit points.

Comment: Note that the empty set contains no points, so every point in it is a limit point. (Think about it like this: you can't find a member of the empty set that *isn't* a limit point.)

Comment: I don't understand why "the empty set contains no points, so every point in it is a limit point". The content in your parentheses makes me more confused. Besides, could you please take a look at the above link and answer the following two questions when you have time?

Comment: "∅ has no limit point"  Yes so *every* limit point it has, all zero of them, are in the empty set.  So this is a *positive* statement for $\emptyset$.

Comment: A statement is "vacuously true" if the hypothesis is false.  The empty set has no points.  So there are no  neighborhoods around any points.  So no neighborhoods contain points outside of the empty set.  So all neighborhood (all zero of them) around every point of the empty set (all zero of them) are completely contained in the empty set.  So the statement is true for the empty set.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've searched for "vacuous truth" and now I see it. The empty set has no point, so every statement that characterizes the points in it can be both true and false, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every k is A $\iff $ there is no k that is not A.

So every point of the empty set is a pink alligator that eats square circles... because the empty set does not have any points that are not pink alligators that eat square circles...  because the empty has no points at all so none of them can avoid being a pink alligator that eat square circles.

To the statement is true for the empty set.  Every point in $\emptyset$ has property $X$ because there are no points in $\emptyset$ that *don't* have property $X$.

Every point *is* a limit point.  And every point is not a limit point.  And every point is green.  And every point is not green.  This is because there are zero points all "all of zero" is .... zero.  And zero of the points are limit points. So all points are limit points because zero is all the points there are and zero are limit points.

So that is not a counter example.

1)  Yes, that was a typo.

2)Because $r$ defines *one* neighborhood.  We must prove this is true for *all* neighborhoods.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've searched for "vacuous truth" and now I see it. The empty set has no point, so every statement that characterizes the points in it can be both true and false, right?

Comment: Almost.  They are all true.  But they can't be false.  Another way of viewing it is: the empty set is the only set where "all elements of" and "no elements of" are the same thing.  So "all elements are P" and "no elements of P" are the same thing.  And they are both true.  Also true is "all elements are not P" and "no elements are not P".  However none of those statements can be false.  They are true because there are no elements.  But they can't be false because there can't be a counter example.

Answer (score 0):

For the open set part, you are asked to show whether the following statement is correct:

Let $E$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $p\in E$, then $p$ is a limit point of $E$.

Your counterexample by letting $E=\emptyset$ is not correct. Because by definition, empty set contains no element, which means you can't select element from it, hence the if part of the above statement is false. Then for the statement $P\rightarrow Q$, if $P$ is false, no matter whether $Q$ is true or false, we say $P\rightarrow Q$ is true. Therefore, for $E=\emptyset$, we know the statement is true.

For the proof in your link:

1. Yes. $q_s=(x_1+s,y_1)$.
2. We are asked to show $p$ is a limit point of $E$, which means for any $\epsilon>0$, we need to find a $q_\epsilon\in E\cap B(p,\epsilon)\setminus\{p\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more easily by noting that $\mathbb R^2$ has no isolated points. A  point $p$ in a space $X$ is isolated iff $\{p\}$ is open.

Let $p\in U\subset R^2$ where $U$ is open.   If $V$ is any nbhd of $p,$ then there exists open $V'$ with $p\in V'\subset V.$

Now  $U\cap V'$ is open and not empty (as it contains $p$) so $\phi \ne U\cap V'\ne \{p\}.$ So there exists $q\in U\cap V'$ with $q\ne p.$

So any nbhd $V$ of  $p$ contains a point $q$ with $p\ne q\in U.$

Comment: This approach makes sense as well, thanks for sharing! Sorry for not having the right to upvote.

Comment: I think it is easier than the approach in the textbook. I think it is better to learn some general toplogy before, or along with, the theory of metric spaces, as many results about metric spaces are true for much broader classes of spaces and can often be  more readily proven, or grasped, without reference to metrics, vectors, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is any easier. You avoid vectors and the basis here, but they just reappear in the proof that $\{p\}$ is not open.